# Filter NA for several columns individually

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse, na

I am making longitudinal line-plots with ggplot, for those I need the dataset only to keep observations where each subject has exactly two timepoints (Pre & Post) which are non-NA. Since there are five different "Tests" it should be allowed that a subject has both timepoints NonNA for Test1 but two NA for Test2, as long as the subjectID's pair is both equal for each Test individually (since each plot is plotted individually later).

To filter to this I tried e.g.

```
dat_all%>%
group_by(SubjectID) %>% 
filter(sum(!is.na(Test1 & Test2 & ...))==2)
```

or

```
dat_all%>%
group_by(SubjectID) %>% 
filter(!any(is.na(c(Test1, Test2, ...)))) %>%
filter(any(Time %in% "Post")) %>%
filter(any(Time %in% "Pre"))
```

or

```
dat_all%>%
group_by(SubjectID, Timepoint) %>% 
filter(!any(is.na(c(Test1, Test2, ...)))) %>%
```

Each subject has variable amount of timepoints and NAs. All solutions omit either all na (e.g. like complete cases) or only retain non_NA pairs per subjects for all variables together (sort of as if the timepoint argument is ignored in: group_by(SubjectID, Timepoint)).

What can I do?

P.S.:Sorry for not providing a reproduciable example, the data. Not sure where to find a dataset like that.

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry for bing unclear.

Comment: you can always do `dput(df)` to show your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `if_all` - after grouping by 'SubjectID', loop over the 'Test' columns in `if_all`, extract the values of each column where the 'Time' values are 'Post' and 'Pre' separately, check for non-NA with `!is.na`, get the count of non-NA on the logical vector with `sum`, check if the 'Pre', 'Post' count non-NA are same (`==`), `if_all` returns TRUE only if all the `Test` columns return TRUE from the earlier comparison, thus `filter`ing only those groups that have same paired non-NA count for all 'Test' columns

```
library(dplyr)
dat_all%>%
group_by(SubjectID) %>%
filter(if_all(starts_with("Test"),  ~ 
              sum(!is.na(.x[Time %in% "Post"])) ==
              sum(!is.na(.x[Time %in% "Pre"])))) %>%
 ungroup
```